# How to generate images on the fly in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, graphics, image

As the title says, how can generate (and display) images on the fly for simple charting, resizing etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `System.Drawing` namespace.

Add a reference to `System.Drawing` assembly. Create a new `Bitmap` class. Call `CreateGraphics` on it. Use the returned `Graphics` object to do your drawing. Set the `Response.ContentType` to the appropriate image MIME type. Finally save the `Bitmap` to the `Response.Output` stream.

Answer (score 3):

For charting, you may want to look into the ASP.NET Chart Control.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check the caution about System.Drawing and ASP.NET http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx
If I were doing it now, I'd use WPF http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF-Image-to-WebPage.aspx